# Classes representing items in an RPG game

Tags: c#, object-oriented, inheritance, interface, role-playing-game

I wrote a little program in C# that contains classes representing Items in RPG game. I wanted to have access to all inherited classes parameters from list contains parent Item class instances, so this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface SpecialObject
{
    int GetIntParameter
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface ElementalsObject
{
    int[] GetElementalsParameters
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    private string _name;
    private int _cost;

    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public int cost
    {
        get { return _cost; }
    }

    public Item(string name, int cost)
    {
        _name = name;
        _cost = cost;
    }
}

public class Weapon : Item, SpecialObject, ElementalsObject
{
    private int dmgs;
    private int[] elementalsDmgs;

    public int GetIntParameter
    {
        get { return dmgs; }
    }

    public int[] GetElementalsParameters
    {
        get { return elementalsDmgs; }
    }

    public Weapon(string name, int cost, int dmgs, int[] elementalsDmgs = null) : base(name, cost)
    {
        if (elementalsDmgs != null)
            this.elementalsDmgs = elementalsDmgs;
        else
            this.elementalsDmgs = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        this.dmgs = dmgs;
    }
}

public class Armor : Item, SpecialObject, ElementalsObject
{
    private int armorPts;
    private int[] elementalsArmorPts;

    public int GetIntParameter
    {
        get { return armorPts; }
    }

    public int[] GetElementalsParameters
    {
        get { return elementalsArmorPts; }
    }

    public Armor(string name, int cost, int armorPts, int[] elementalsArmorPts = null) : base(name, cost)
    {
        if (elementalsArmorPts != null)
            this.elementalsArmorPts = elementalsArmorPts;
        else
            this.elementalsArmorPts = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        this.armorPts = armorPts;
    }
}

public class Food : Item, SpecialObject
{
    private int _hungryRestorePts;

    public int GetIntParameter
    {
        get { return _hungryRestorePts; }
    }

    public Food(string name, int cost, int hungryRestorePts) : base(name, cost)
    {
        _hungryRestorePts = hungryRestorePts;
    }
}

class Equipment
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        items.AddRange(new Item[] { new Item("Stone", 1),
                                    new Armor("Steel Helmet", 80, 10),
                                    new Weapon("Great Sword", 120, 80),
                                    new Armor("Storm Cuirass", 1000, 120, new int[4] {0, 0, 0, 60}),
                                    new Weapon("Fire Spear", 1400, 60, new int[4] {0, 80, 0, 0}),
                                    new Food("Apple", 5, 10) });

        string[] el = new string[4] { "Water", "Fire", "Earth", "Wind" };

        foreach(Item i in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + i.name + ", Cost: " + i.cost);
            if(i is SpecialObject)
            {
                //SpecialObject so = i as SpecialObject;
                SpecialObject so = (SpecialObject)i;
                Console.WriteLine(" Damages/ArmorPts/HungryRestorePts: " + so.GetIntParameter);
            }

            if(i is ElementalsObject)
            {
                ElementalsObject eo = i as ElementalsObject;
                Console.WriteLine(" Elementals parameters: ");

                for (int e = 0; e < el.Length; e++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  " + el[e] + ": " + eo.GetElementalsParameters[e] + ", ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about it? Is it good code? If no then how I can write it better? :)

Comment: You might be interested to read https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I put code in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> public interface SpecialObject
> {
>     int GetIntParameter
>     {
>         get;
>     }
> }
>
> public interface ElementalsObject
> {
>     int[] GetElementalsParameters
>     {
>         get;
>     }
> }
> ```

1. What does "object" mean? If it refers to a domain concept, then it should have a more specific name (any "thing" can be an "object"); if it's a technical term, then it should be removed (all classes are objects, no need to say so explicitly).
2. `GetIntParameter` and `GetElementalsParameters` are pretty poor names. What does the parameter represent? Name the property after that, not after how it *may* be supplied to the implementing class.

> ```
> public class Item
> {
>     private string _name;
>     private int _cost;
>
>     public string name
>     {
>         get { return _name; }
>     }
>
>     public int cost
>     {
>         get { return _cost; }
>     }
>
>     public Item(string name, int cost)
>     {
>         _name = name;
>         _cost = cost;
>     }
> }
> ```

This is ok although it doesn't really do much (or anything), just a class holding two properties. You could make the code shorter by writing it like this instead. And remember public properties should be *PascalCase*.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; private set; } // private set only required if not using C# 6.0
    public int Cost { get; private set; }

    public Item(string name, int cost)
    {
        Name = name;
        Cost = cost;
    }
}
```

So now we see a class implementing your interfaces.

> ```
> public class Weapon : Item, SpecialObject, ElementalsObject
> {
>     private int dmgs;
>     private int[] elementalsDmgs;
>
>     public int GetIntParameter
>     {
>         get { return dmgs; }
>     }
>
>     public int[] GetElementalsParameters
>     {
>         get { return elementalsDmgs; }
>     }
>
>     public Weapon(string name, int cost, int dmgs, int[] elementalsDmgs = null) : base(name, cost)
>     {
>         if (elementalsDmgs != null)
>             this.elementalsDmgs = elementalsDmgs;
>         else
>             this.elementalsDmgs = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
>
>         this.dmgs = dmgs;
>     }
> }
> ```

First of all the constructor can be shortened by assigning `elementalsDmgs` like so: `this.elementalsDmgs = elementalsDmgs ?? new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };`.

Now you see how the property names on your interfaces are unhelpful. What does `GetIntParameter` mean or return on a `Weapon`, `Armor`, or `Food` object, aside from "an int"? Who knows. What is the meaning of the values that `GetElementalsParameters` returns on `Weapon` and `Armor`? Well I know it returns something to do with "elementals" (whatever that is - maybe that word makes sense in your domain), but who knows the meaning of the parameters?

The much bigger problem is that `GetIntParameter` actually has no meaning; your classes have `int` parameters, so you created an interface to represent it so you can get the value from all classes implementing that interface. But on `Food` and `Armor` it contains a number of "points", and on `Weapon` it refers to "damages". (Assuming I'm interpreting "dmgs" correctly - which is another issue, don't skip the vowels! "dmgs" only makes sense to you, everyone else has to guess what it might mean.) The fact that they're always `int` does not make them in any way related, and is not a shared behaviour or functionality.

> ```
> class Equipment
> {
>     public static void Test()
>     {
>         ...
>         string[] el = new string[4] { "Water", "Fire", "Earth", "Wind" };
>         ...
>         Console.WriteLine(" Elementals parameters: ");
>         ...
>         Console.WriteLine("  " + el[e] + ": " + eo.GetElementalsParameters[e] + ", ");
> ```

Ah, so the elementals parameters are "Water", "Fire", "Earth", "Wind". So the `ElementalsObject` should have properties with those names, each of which can be assigned an `int`, rather than a property with an int array. I mean, who can guarantee that the values of the int array were even supplied in the correct order?

> ```
> if(i is SpecialObject)
>       SpecialObject so = (SpecialObject)i;
>
> if(i is ElementalsObject)
>       ElementalsObject eo = i as ElementalsObject;
> ```

It's not clear why you do this in two different ways just a few lines apart, but neither is the best way to do it as both involve casting twice. What you should do is this, as it only casts once:

```
 var o = i as SpecialObject;
 if (o != null)
     // cast is valid.
```

---

I don't really want to take the time to rewrite the code myself as this doesn't feel like "real" code, more like an experiment. But some suggestions are:

- Rename `SpecialObject` to something clearer; rename `GetIntParameter` to something to do with points.
- Rename the `ElementalsObject` interface to something clearer; remove current property and replace with properties of actual names (Fire, Water, etc).
- Consider whether the above should even be interfaces. To me this calls for a base class for these different types of "items", so you don't have to implement the interface properties on each type of item.
- Use a factory for item creation. Creating an item like so `new Armor("Storm Cuirass", 1000, 120, new int[4] {0, 0, 0, 60})` is no good as it's too time consuming and error prone.
- You shouldn't have to say `if (i is SpecialObject)` and `if (i is ElementalsObject)`. Use polymorphism to call a method on the objects which returns the correct result per object type. (In this case, you could simply override `ToString()` in the classes, but again this requires a proper base class structure.)

Comment: Thanks for that exhausting answer, I will rewrite code in a way that you showed here. :)

Comment: Can you tell me more about last point of your  suggestions? What i have to put into ToString function?

Comment: The ToString is an example for your specific usage; i.e. since you are only using the objects in Console.Writeline, you could for example override ToString in a base class to return the string `"Name: " + Name + ", Cost: " + Cost`; then when you create a base class implementing points, you can override ToString something like: `return base.ToString() + "\nDamages/ArmorPts/HungryRestorePts: " + Points;` etc. Then when you iterate through the items, you can just say `Console.Writeline(item)` and it will print the item details in the way you want and with all the specifics for that item type.

Comment: I changed code, what do you think now?